# Why am I getting an "error: declaration of 'Coin::Coin()' outside of class is not definition" message?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am just learning about classes in C++, and I am trying to create this `Coin` class that simulates a coin flip with a method called `toss()` that will return either 0 or 1 which represent heads or tails respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Coin {
    private:

    public:
        Coin();
        int toss();
};

Coin::Coin();

int Coin::toss() {

    int num;

    num = rand() % 2;

    return num;

}

int main() {

    Coin C;

    cout << C.toss() << endl;

}
```

I keep getting an error that says: `error: declaration of 'Coin::Coin()' outside of class is not definition`. I am assuming that I did not declare my constructor correctly, but I am not sure.

Comment: Replace `Coin::Coin();` with `Coin::Coin(){}` outside class

Comment: You could just remove the constructor from the header and cpp file since it does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465573/declaration-of-xxx-outside-of-class-is-not-definition-error

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that you're trying to declare the constructor outside the class when you wrote `Coin::Coin();`.

To **solve** this replace `Coin::Coin();` with `Coin::Coin(){}` as shown below:

```
class Coin {
    private:

    public:
        Coin();
        int toss();
};
//----------v--->semicolon removed from here
Coin::Coin()    //this is a definition now 
{
}
```